# テーブルAからselectした結果を元に複数件データをテーブルBにinsertする

Tags: sql

以下のようなテーブルデータがそれぞれあるとします。

テーブルA

| id | data | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | a |
| 2 | bbb | a |
| 3 | ccc | a |
| 4 | ddd | b |
| 5 | eee | b |

テーブルB

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx |
| 2 | yyy |

---

テーブルAから、例えば以下のようにセレクトし、その結果をテーブルBにインサートして以下の結果のようにしたいです。

１回のSQL文で実現可能でしょうか？
実現可能ならどのようにSQL文を書けばよいでしょうか？

```
select data from A where type = 'a'
```

テーブルB (インサート後)

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx |
| 2 | yyy |
| 3 | aaa |
| 4 | bbb |
| 5 | ccc |

Comment: 個々が参考になるかもしれません。[【SQL】INSERT文の書き方：サンプル多数あり](https://oreno-it.info/archives/2258)

Comment: `id`列の管理は誰の責任でどのようなルールしょうか？ `INSERT`する側？ 普通はテーブル定義で自動採番させたりしますが。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントで触れましたが、`id`列の採番を`INSERT`する側に委ねるのではなく、テーブルが（テーブル定義として）責任を持つべきです。具体的には大抵のSQLには`AUTO_INCREMENT`のような機能が用意されています。
（payanecoさんに続く意味でMySQLで書きます。）

テーブルBの定義が

```
create table B (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT, data varchar(10), INDEX (id));
```

となっていれば、`INSERT`する側は`id`列に`NULL`を与えるだけで済みます。

```
insert into B select NULL, data from A where type = 'a';
```

Answer (score 1):

テーブルBのidに続けて連番を振る目的ならば、MySQL 8.0以上であれば下記のSQLで実現可能です。
(連番を作成するSQLはデータベースによって変わります)

```
insert into B select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) + (select COUNT(1) from B), data from A where type = 'a';
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/huX9CKSuvqVH6qbjTvq8M7/0)